# Remove the first 4 characters from each row of a text file

Tags: powershell

I have a file full of lines like this. There are always the same amount of semicolons and there is always a 3 character string before the first semicolon.

RT2;SS1234567;INV RED;13.06.2021;14.06.2021;154;Out;
RT2;XX1234567;INV RED;04.05.2021;14.06.2021;1472;Out;
RT2;FF1234567;INV RED;04.05.2021;14.06.2021;1472;Out;
RT2;LL1234567;INV RED;13.05.2021;14.06.2021;1472;Out;

I want to remove the beginning 3 character string and the semicolon from each row.

This is how I'm pulling in the file, it's full of blank lines and rows I need to remove

```
#import the file removing the first row and removing blank rows
$inFile = Get-Content -Path ($InFileDir + $InFileName)|Select-Object -Skip 1|? {$_.trim() -ne "" }

# Removes the (12334 rows affected) line that's added by sql
$inFile = $inFile|Where-Object {$_ -notlike '(*)'}

# Source file is two different sql table exports appended to each other, store the different headers
$header1 = 'RT1;Polref;Tranaction;Eff Dte;Process Dte;Fund;Movement;'
$header2 = 'RT3;Polref;Tranaction;Eff Dte;Process Dte;Fund;Qty;Amt;'

#Get some file positions
$RowBeforeheader2Index = $InFile.IndexOf($header2) -1
$header1Index = $InFile.IndexOf($header1)
$header2Index = $InFile.IndexOf($header2)
$LastRow = $inFile.Length -1

$outFile[$header1Index..$RowBeforeheader2Index]

foreach ($row in $outFile)
{
    //perform a substring on the row and add to $var
}

$var|Out-file 'C:\temp\output.txt'
```

I'm not sure how to fill out the foreach loop to achieve my desired result. (I'm just calling it $var for for this example...I'm not that unimaginative)

EDIT:

I ended up changing $var to a list and used the following code in the foreach loop

```
$var = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

foreach($row in $outFile)
{
    $var.Add($row.Substring(4))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you can remove a fixed number of characters and assuming that each line has at least 4 characters, you can simply call `.Substring()` on your array of strings (lines):

```sh
# Sample input
$outFile = 'RT2;SS1234567', 'RT2;SS1234568', 'RT2;SS1234569'

# Remove the first 4 characters from each line (array element).
# (Use $var = ... to assign the output to a variable).
$outFile.Substring(4)
```

Note that even though `$outFile` is an *array*, the `.Substring()` method is called on *each element*, which is a PowerShell feature known as [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$data = @"
RT2;SS1234567;INV RED;13.06.2021;14.06.2021;154;Out;
RT2;XX1234567;INV RED;04.05.2021;14.06.2021;1472;Out;
RT2;FF1234567;INV RED;04.05.2021;14.06.2021;1472;Out;
RT2;LL1234567;INV RED;13.05.2021;14.06.2021;1472;Out;
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Header @("col1","col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7")

$data | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty col1 | ConvertTo-Csv | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Set-Content $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\output.csv
```

NOTE - Use `Select-Object -Skip 2`, if `ConvertTo-Csv` generates an additional column **`#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`**, else you can use `Select-Object -Skip 1`.

Comment: Using `ConvertTo-Csv` is a good approach but your code will eat the first row from the data and leave all values quoted with double-quotes. and separated by commata. Try: `$data | select * -ExcludeProperty col1 | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -QuoteFields '' -Delimiter ';' | Select-Object -Skip 1`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that. If your operation is really as simple as deleting the first column, you can do it like this. Assuming the content of `$outFile` in your example corresponds to your listing and `$var = @()` has been set earlier in your script, you can put the following into your foreach loop:

```
$null,$row = $row -split ';' # Turn the string into an array and dump the first element.
$var += $row -join ';' # Turn the array into a string using ; as delimiter
```

The content of `$var` should then look like this:

```
SS1234567;INV RED;13.06.2021;14.06.2021;154;Out;
XX1234567;INV RED;04.05.2021;14.06.2021;1472;Out;
FF1234567;INV RED;04.05.2021;14.06.2021;1472;Out;
LL1234567;INV RED;13.05.2021;14.06.2021;1472;Out;
```

Answer (score 0):

> --replace

is the easiest way to remove the number of characters in each line of multiline text.

```
$content = $inFile = Get-Content -Path ($InFileDir + $InFileName)|Select-Object -Skip 1    
$content -replace "(?m)^.{4}"
```

multiline mode is enabled by the ***m*** flag, so that ^ and $ will match beginning of string and end of string multiple times. (as divided by \n)